# Which is correct between "is called" and "is called the" when writing a definition?

Tags: articles

> The special type of periodic motion where the restoring force is
> proportional to the magnitude of the displacement of the body from the
> mean position and acts in the direction opposite to the displacement
> is called simple harmonic motion.

> The special type of periodic motion where the restoring force is
> proportional to the magnitude of the displacement of the body from the
> mean position and acts in the direction opposite to the displacement
> is called **the** simple harmonic motion.

I suspect that I have been following the 2nd format of writing definitions my whole life. However,  now I am concerned about its validity. Which one of the two formats is correct? Should there be a "the" at the end (2nd format) or should I not write "the" (1st format)?

Comment: Hello, ttbas. What do raw Google searches for "the simple harmonic motion" and "simple harmonic motion" -"the simple harmonic motion" suggest? What usage does say the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion) article employ? // To add a little 'clout', prominence, to the term, it's good to put it in italics the first time it's used in a definition. But no definite article here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the first, **without** *the.*

In English, "simple harmonic motion" is the name of that particular form of movement. That's even indicated with the verb *call.* English does not use an article with names when they occur simply like this.

> [This] special type of periodic motion ... is called Dave.
> [This] special type of periodic motion ... is called simple harmonic motion.

There **are** occasions when names might get an article ("the Donald"; "an Andrew"; "the London in Ontario, not England") but those are indicating a **particular thing with that name,** not simply naming something.

Comment: It's slightly more complicated, because you can't say "That thing is called *chair*" (it's "a chair") but I'll leave that particular nuance to someone more skilled.

Comment: It's certainly got subtleties "Dendrocopos minor is called the lesser spotted woodpecker", "the sequence of bytes at the start of a file is called the header", "Carnot's discovery is called the third law of thermodynamics", etc. Even maybe "...called the simple harmonic motion of the system".